# retrieve all record from one table and particular record from other

Tags: mysql, sql

**tbl_cmp**

```
usr_id | cmp_name | usr_fname |cmp_addr
```

**tbl_usr**

```
cmp_usr_id |cmp_id | cmp_usr_fname | cnt_status
```

I am trying query retrieve data from both at a time for ::
retrieve all data from tbl_cmp
but
retrieve only field from tbl_usr that cnt_status=1

I tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_cmp
JOIN tbl_usr ON tbl_usr.cmp_id = tbl_cmp.usr_id
WHERE tbl_usr.cnt_status =1
```

but it shows only record that has cnt_status=1 not all record from first table

Comment: just to clarify, in the join clause you join on the cmd_id and the usr_id, then what is the cmp_usr_id for? it seems to me that you are trying to compare 2 different fields that are not related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_users LEFT JOIN tbl_cmp_user 
ON tbl_cmp_user.cmp_id = tbl_users.usr_id 
AND tbl_cmp_user.cnt_status =1
```

Comment: @Anu Please accept this answer if you think it is appropriate to you.
See [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

Use **LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_users
Left outer JOIN tbl_cmp_user 
ON tbl_cmp_user.cmp_id = tbl_users.usr_id
and tbl_cmp_user.cnt_status =1
```

See Examples of left outer join [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: It shows only record that has cnt_status=1
want to retrieve all records from tbl_user
addition col with those who have cnt_status=1 
if cnt_status is not 1 it have to show 0

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a cross join, because you do not have a join condition between the tables:

```
select c.*, u.*
from tbl_cmp c cross join
     (select *
      from tbl_users u
      where u.cnt_status = 1
     ) u
```

You can express this without the subquery as:

```
select c.*, u.*
from tbl_cmp c cross join
     tbl_users u
where u.cnt_status = 1
```

I prefer the subquery version, because it makes the condition on tbl_users quite apparent.  In a more complicated query, the WHERE clause could be quite separated from where the table appears in the FROM clause.